# Are there any resources for becoming a Cygwin "power user"?

Tags: windows, unix, cygwin

I've got it configured, but I want more from it...maybe Cygwin isn't the right tool, but I like how it provides a *nix-like environment within Windows.

Comment: It sounds like you want to know about Cygwin itself, but the skills needed to be a "power user" of Cygwin are not all that different from Unix itself.  Maybe you could clarify that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found Cygwin to be very useful in the past.  FWIW, lately however I've shied away from it in favor of the following:

1. [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)
2. [Unixutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

I like these tools even better.

Comment: Unixutils is definitely nice. I use that more often myself, but I do use Cygwin occasionally.

Comment: GnuWin32 (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) seems more active.  Is there a reason to use Unixutils instead?

Comment: @James no reason that I know of, unixutils is what I was familiar with.

Answer (score 12):

If you've already read the [Cygwin User Guide](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/), take a look at [Ten Steps To Higher Cygwin Productivity](http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2006/08/14/ten_steps_to_higher_cygwin_productivity.html).

Also, if you're using a shell such as bash in Cygwin, and you're familiar with Emacs, consider using [Eshell](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html) (the Emacs shell) instead.

Comment: That 10 steps article is quite dated now. Specifically: 2. Use rxvt instead, no need to install the full X if you don't need it. 5. Windows native PostgreSQL is now available. 8. Why cygwin Apache instead of native Apache?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite interested in this question myself. I've used the [Cygwin Setup guide](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jessies/wikis/CygwinSetup.wiki) to get set up, but it doesn't get you all the way. One thing that I learned from it, though, is that it recommends leaving the setup.exe in the directory with Cygwin so that you can quickly add packages, since apt-get apparently doesn't work that well in Cygwin. The article also talks about cyg-get as an alternative.